# ignoring jshint Unnecessary semicolon error

Tags: jshint

I am using jshint which gives me the error "Unnecessary semicolon".
I do not control the file in question and I would like to ignore this error.
I am not able to find any such option on the [jshint doc page](http://jshint.com/docs/options/)

Answer (score 5):

Turns out you can ignore any error message by setting an option for specific error numbers:

```
"-W032": true
```

Comment: Question is - where do you find the specific error number?